# Transform a function form one form to another

Tags: integration

can anyone help me transform a function of this form:

$$ \int f(x) \ e^{-(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2} \ dx $$

into a form that looks like this:

$$ \int g(y) \ e^{-y^2} \ dy $$

reason:
I have to solve the first integral using Gauss–Hermite quadrature which can solve only the second type of integrals.

I have tried

$$ \int f(x*\sigma + \mu) \ e^{-x^2} \ dx $$

but it's not the same ([trasnformed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%28%282%2ax%2b1%29%2ae%5E%28-x%5E2%29,-Inf,Inf%29), [correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%28x%2ae%5E%28-%28%28x-1%29/2%29%5E2%29,-Inf,Inf%29)). Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here.

Comment: It should be dy in second integral

Comment: @exploringnet yes thank you. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $$\dfrac{x-\mu}{\sigma}=y\ =>\dfrac{dx}\sigma=dy$$
and $${\sigma}{f(\sigma y +\mu)}=g(y)$$

I's sigma times whole expression you gave. The $dx=\sigma dy$ and not just $dy$